# Activity leaked window token exception

Tags: android

I am showing user a dialog inside a runnable and giving him two buttons, YES and NO. If User presses NO, i am just finishing up the activity. if user presses YES i want to start another activity. Here is the dialog code:

```
ad.setTitle("Title");
                    ad.setMessage("Do you want to exit?");
                    ad.setIcon(R.drawable.common_signin_btn_icon_light);
                    ad.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Yes",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {

                                    // OPEN UP REGISTRATION ACTIVITY AGAIN
                                    ad.dismiss();
                            finish();
                            startActivity(new Intent(
                                    ActivityCodeVerification.this,
                                    ActivityRegister.class));
                                }
                            });
                    ad.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "No,Exit",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
ad.dismiss();
                            finish();
                            startActivity(new Intent(
                                    ActivityCodeVerification.this,
                                    ActivityRegister.class));
                                }
                            });
```

Whenever any button gets pressed, I am getting this exception:

```
Activity com.Rp.chatout.ActivityCodeVerification has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4055a530 that was originally added here
```

What am i doing wrong?? 
                    ad.show();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add call method dismiss() in both cases before finishing Activity.

This exception raises because you are keeping reference to the Activity in your Dialog, while the Activity is already destroyed.

Comment: Please look at my code now. i am still getting the error.

Comment: this whole thing i am doing is inside a runnalbe inside handler

Comment: @UsmanRiaz well, it means you have reference to the activity in your handler. Call handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null); or handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);.

Comment: Very nice answer. I just did that and read  your comment. was the same. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `dismiss()` before exiting the Activity from where you are executing above code.

All windows & dialogs should be closed before leaving an Activity.

Comment: this whole thing i am doing is inside a runnalbe inside handler